# Replace link title

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to perform a regular expression on every link in my html page's attribute title, based on the following rules:

1. The link is equal to the anchor text.
2. The link does *not* have title attributes.

I have written this code:

```
$x = 'gg <a href="#">Anchor 1</a>, <a href="#" title="text">Anchor 2</a>';
echo preg_replace('/\<a([^<]*)(?!title)>([^<]+)\<\/a/isu', '<a${1} title="${2}">${2}</a', $x);
```

But I get this unintended result:

```
gg <a href="#" title="Anchor 1">Anchor 1</a>, <a href="#" title="text" title="Anchor 2">Anchor 2</a>
```

The second link has 2 title attributes. Why is this not working as intended?  How can I fix it?

Comment: use a html dom parser to do this, not regexp

Comment: The lookahead assertion `?!` does not mask the `[^<]*` placeholder. It's just a nop where you placed it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a nofollow attribute to link if no title tag present using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160645/add-a-nofollow-attribute-to-link-if-no-title-tag-present-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your expression:

```
<a([^<]*)
```

This matches all the way up to the next opening bracket but is stopped by the `>` further down in the expression; in the meantime it skips over `(?!title)`.

That said, this problem is better expressed in the HTML domain instead of text domain:

```
$contents = <<<'EOS'
gg <a href="#">Anchor 1</a>, <a href="#" title="text">Anchor 2</a>
EOS;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($contents);
// find all anchors
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor) {
        if (!$anchor->hasAttribute('title')) {
                $anchor->setAttribute('title', $anchor->textContent);
        }
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

To only save the nodes you're interested in you will have to use this kind of construct:

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->childNodes as $childNode) {
        echo $doc->saveHTML($childNode);
}
```

Comment: It's fine, thx, but DOMDocument add doctype and html tags, but I need modify partials html blocks

Comment: @gvozd1989 I gave a solution for that too.